# Job search in Europe from other countries for IT professionals

Tags: software-industry, job-search, hiring-process, software-development, europe

Ways to get a software developer jobs in Europe countries.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “mandatory way to get a job”?

Comment: am I've to clear  any exam?.. even I got a referral. Or am I've to do any course or anything whatever. I need to know the mandatory tasks.

Comment: Thought you did the same for your requirements. That's why it comes first in your mind. anyway good luck with your attitude to get lot of opportunity in future. And if you don't know the answer just sit back and look who post valuable answer.

Comment: Where are you from? That might help us establish the differences.

Comment: @Borgh I'm from India.

Comment: @virlino I thought 'thousands' of money.

Comment: Jobserve.com  Or, join a multinational in India, then angle for a transfer.

Comment: @Mawg That is also a good idea. But it is my wish so only I'm asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to qualify and apply for a work visa once you have an offer letter.

As for IT companies hiring, having experience or a degree in a related field will raise your chances considerably.

As has been said, IT professions are not regulated in the way doctors or lawyers for instance are, so basically good luck!

Of course ability to communicate is important.

Depending on the company and the country, good english may suffice, others will require you to speak the local language.

Knowing the local language to navigate daily life will be highly advantageous as well.

Comment: Beyond that ..beyond offer letter am I've to qualify in any other things. Not for working level, for basics aspects to work in Europe like, need to know one of the European language or any other things like that?

Comment: @JosephM ah well, of course you need to be able to communicate. The language you need depends on the company. Some are fine if you speak good english. Others require you to speak the local language.If you live there,want to be able to shop or navigate through daily live, speaking the local language will be highly advantageous.

Comment: Okay, So you said that is not mandatory. That is highly important to survive there. Because somebody told me that , language known is mandatory that is one a qualification to work in Europe. That's why I'm asking you. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JosephM only if you want to become a citizen as far as I know. Potentially if you desire to migrate there but I don't think so. Certainly not for work. Not by law. But talk to the company about the languages you speak and ask if that works for them. ALSO:contact authorities about requirements for work visas, don't rely on other sources.

Comment: Okay. But I don't think about getting citizenship. I know that process would consume more level of process.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know *"IT"* is not a profession regulated by law and public authorities and in general to practice IT work you do not require a certain recognized and certified degree,  unlike for instance the doctors and surgeons, lawyers and barristers, architects and many other professions.

If you meet your future employers expectations regarding your skills to only legal requirements to work in IT are then the generic requirements, primarily VISA and work permits.

Specific titles will be protected, for instance in the UK you can only call yourself an "ICT Technician (ICTTech)" when registered with the Engineering Council in the UK. 
 You can query the [EU regulated professions database](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/tools-databases/regprof/index.cfm?action=homepage) as there are differences among EU countries as to what professions are protected and where and which requirements they have.

To use any of your existing professional & educational  degrees / diploma's / academic titles etc. please note that [there is no EU wide recognition of academic diplomas](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/education/university/recognition/index_en.htm) and may therefore need to go through a national procedure to get your academic degree or diploma recognized (which will then only be recognized in that specific EU country).

Comment: I saw something there that requires the details about the qualification that done in one of the European countries. What if I wish to work there with getting a qualification in other country? Is this the site for internal purpose or external?

Comment: https://www.enic-naric.net/individual-wishing-to-studywork-abroad.aspx

Comment: It is not only for Europe. But helpful. Thanks